# How to return value in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to return the  integer array element after finding the 3 consecutive number problem please tell me where i am going wrong to return the array element inside from the loop.i want to return value in array and catch that element in another array.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace interview
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[5]{1,3,4,5,5};
        int[] arr1 = GetOriginalScore(3,arr);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr1[i]);
        }
    }
    public static int[] GetOriginalScore(int input1, int[] input2)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < input1; i++)
        {
            int a=((3 * input2[i] + 3) / 3);
            if (a == (input2[i] + 1))
            {
                return  input2[i];
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `please tell me where i am going to wrong` didn't the compiler tell you something as well? Or in what way do your expected results differ from the actual ones?

Answer (score 4):

```
public static int[] GetOriginalScore(int input1, int[] input2)
```

here, you specify that you want to return an array. If you want to return an element:

```
public static int GetOriginalScore(int input1, int[] input2)
```

Comment: but i want to return in array

Comment: Then you might want to mark the array as an out parameter. Or rewrite your question and tell us what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the code from,

```
public static int[] GetOriginalScore(int input1, int[] input2)
```

to

```
public static int GetOriginalScore(int input1, int[] input2)
```

The function will look like this

```
public static int GetOriginalScore(int input1, int[] input2)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < input1; i++)
        {
            int a=((3 * input2[i] + 3) / 3);
            if (a == (input2[i] + 1))
            {
                return  input2[i];
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @DrCopyPaste You should have checked properly!

Comment: True, but you could also have commented your answer in the first place, too ;)